# Puppet: unable to get hiera variable

Tags: puppet, hiera

I've been using hiera for several weeks now and all was working fine til few days ago when i started to get that kind of message:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find data item nom in any Hiera data file and no default supplied on node d0puppetclient.victor-buck.com
>
> Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>
> Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

So i tried to make a very simple test to check if the problem came from my last code changes and i'm still getting this message. I can't get hiera variable anymore.
    Below the test i made:

hiera.yaml:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata

:hierarchy:
  - common
```

site.pp:

```
# /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

case $operatingsystem {
  'Solaris': { include role::solaris }
  'RedHat', 'CentOS': { include redhat::roles::common }
  /^(Debian|Ubuntu)$/: { include role::debian }
#  default: { include role::generic }
}

case $hostname {
  /^d0puppetclient/: { include test }
}
```

test.pp:

```
class test{

  $nom = hiera('nom')

file {"/root/test.txt":
    ensure   => file,
    source   => "/etc/puppet/test.txt.erb",
  }

}
```

test.txt.erb:

```
<%= nom %>
```

Any idea about to fix this? I thought this could be an file access right issue, so i tried to grante access on some files (`755`) and it's not working...

Comment: So what's in `/etc/puppet/hieradata/common.yaml`

Comment: What's `nom`? Where have you defined it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `nom` in your common.yaml in order for it to hold a value. You can set a default value and conditionally create the file if you don't plan on setting it.

```
class test {
  $nom = hiera('nom', false)

  if $nom {
    file { '/root/test.txt':
      ensure => file,
      content => template('test/test.txt.erb')
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how i used `content` instead of `source`. When using `erb` templates you need to specify the `content` using the `template()` function.

[Using Templates](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html)

If you use `source` it is expecting a file rather than an `erb` template.

Hope this helps.